# Windows Phone 7.1 play recorded PCM/WAV audio

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, mediaelement

I'm working on a WP7.1 app that records audio and plays it back. I'm using a MedialElement to playback audio. The MediaElement works fine for playing MP4 (actually M4A files renamed) downloaded from the server. However, when I try to play a recorded file with or without the WAV RIFF header (PCM in both cases) it does not work. It gives me an error code 3001, which I cannot find the definition for anywhere.

Can anyone point me to some sample code on playing recorded audio in WP7.1 that does not use the SoundEffect class. Don't want to use the SoundEffect class because it's meant for short audio clips.

This is how I load the audio file:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile(audioSourceUri.ToString(), FileMode.Open))
    {
        m_mediaElement.SetSource(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This playing code looks good. Issue have to be in storing code. BTW `3001` means `AG_E_INVALID_FILE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the "Average bytes per second" RIFF header value was wrong. I was using the wrong value for the Bits per Sample value, which should've been 16 bit since the microphone records in 16-bit PCM.